# How can I use pandas to calculate the standard deviation of rolling windows

Tags: pandas

Here is my data , I traded three symbol from 20170101 to 20170106
and I record every symbol relized profit.

```
label = ['symbol','date','relized']
list = [['S1','20170101',11111],['S1','20170102',12221],['S1','20170103',33445],['S2','20170102',-32421],['S2','20170103',-12211],['S2','20170104',9331],['S2','20170105',62211],['S2','20170106',92211],['S3','20170102',20444]]

df = pd.DataFrame(list,columns=label)

  symbol      date  relized
0     S1  20170101    11111
1     S1  20170102    12221
2     S1  20170103    33445
3     S2  20170102   -32421
4     S2  20170103   -12211
5     S2  20170104     9331
6     S2  20170105    62211
7     S2  20170106    92211
8     S3  20170102    20444
```

so , if today is 20170103 , the total relized is 33445+(-12211)+20444 ,

and what I want to do is that , my initial capital (parameter name: C) is 500000 and I want to calculate value R which formula is

`R=Std(C + TodayTotalRelized,period=3Days)/Average(Std value of nearly 3 Day, period=3Days)`

Is there any good way ?

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the rolling function.

```
df.rolling(windows=3).std()
```